# How to abort a Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a report params aspx page where I am populating all the parameters that i will later use generatig the report.
When the user hits the "Show Report" button I open another aspx page where I have a ReportDocument `repDoc` object to generate the report. To render the report i use the following code:

```
repDoc.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, false, "Report Name");
```

There are reports that take time and some users prefer to close the page, but still the report is being generated on the server. How can I abort the report after I have called the `ExportToHttpResponse` method in order to avoid rendering reports that nobody will see/use?

Answer (score 0):

use `Response.End()`. It will abort the response.